# Use Cat command with C code

Tags: c, linux, cat

I'm using the cat command for a school project.

What i need is to give a txt file as input to my code and then evaluate the output (saved in a txt file).
So far i'm using this in my command line:

```
cat input_000.txt | ./main > my_output.txt
```

Where ./main is my C code.

The input_000.txt is structured like this:

```
0 a a R 3
1 a b L 4
4 c b R 1
ecc...
```

I have a certain number of lines made of 5 characters (with spaces between them).

How do i get the content of each line in my C code? I've been told so use standard input, but i've always used `scanf`only from keyboard input.

Does it still work in this case?

And how should i save my output? I usually use `fwrite`, but in this case is everything managed by the `cat` command

Comment: Possible duplicate of [read from pipe line by line in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163154/read-from-pipe-line-by-line-in-c).

Comment: "but i've always used `scanf`only from keyboard input." In that case `stdin` was reading from your keyboard. But still it was `stdin`.

Comment: `cat` should be completely unrelated, your first snippet is a classical [useless use of cat](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html). (correct command: `./main <input_000.txt >my_output.txt`)

Comment: @FelixPalmen Why is it useless? I'm reporting the command given by our professor. The input txt goes into C code (which act as a filter) and print the result into the second txt.
[link](http://www.linfo.org/cat.html) here there's a similar example 'cat file1 file2 file3 | sort > file4'

Comment: @MattiaSurricchio well, follow my link. In short, the shell can feed a file to `stdin`, that's what input redirection is for. `cat` is for concatenating, if you only read a single file, it's most of the time useless -- and costs you another process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how pipes works, it sets up so the output of the left-hand side of the pipe will be written to standard input for the right-hand side program.

In short if you can read input from `stdin` (like you do with plain `scanf`) then you won't have to do any changes at all.

Redirection works just about the same. Redirecting to a file (`>`) will make all writes to `stdout` go to the file. Redirecting from a file (`<`) will make all reads from `stdin` come from the file.

Comment: In order to save the output, i can both use fwrite(stdout) and printf?

Comment: @MattiaSurricchio Do you mean that you want to save the output from `printf` (and other functions writing to `stdout`) to also write to a file? Then I suggest you use [the `tee` command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html) instead of redirecting your output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use getline (or `scanf` indeed) to read the `stdin` (fd = 0) and save it in a `char*` in your C code... Then you only need to write in the `stdout` (fd = 1) and your `>` will do the job to write in your file

Answer (score 1):

What you need is something like this inside your function...

```
FILE *input = fopen("input.txt","rw"); //rw (read-write)
FILE *output= fopen("output.txt","rw"); //rw (read-write)
char inputArray[500];
char outputArray[500];

while(fscanf(input,"%s", inputArray) != EOF){
      //read the line and save in 'inputArray'
      //you can also use %c to find each caracter, in your case I think it's better...you can //save each caracter in a array position, or something like that
}

while(number of lines you need or the number of lines from your input file){
      fprintf(output,"%s\n",output); //this will write the string saved in 'outputArray'
}
```

If you don't want to use it...then you can give your main.c the input using < and saving the output >

./main.o < input.txt > output.txt

(something like that, its not safer because the terminal could have the settings to use other type of charset...